# Reverse username from email

Tags: python, reverse

I created a script whereas the output should be "ACER,ONE" however I am stuck how can I place a reverse the username which I ended up "ONE,ACER" as result.

```
email='one.acer@mymail.com'
index = email.index("@")
email_id = email[:index]
email_id = email_id.upper()
print(email_id.replace(email_id[3],","))
# > ONE,ACER
```

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify. Code is unreadable in comments, especially Python code, where whitespace matters. [Edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
",".join("ACER,ONE".split(",")[::-1])
```

In your case, you could do:

```
print(",".join(email.split("@")[0].split(",")[::-1]))
```

as @ox5453 mentioned in the comments, you can also use the built-in reversed method for readability:

```
print(",".join(reversed("ACER,ONE".split(","))))
print(",".join(reversed(email.split("@")[0].split(","))))
```

Comment: I personally prefer the built-in [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function over a negative slice stride because the former is easier to read.

Comment: @0x5453 Agreed.  It is easier to read than negative slicing.

Answer (score 0):

```
email1 ='one.acer@mymail.com'
email2 = print(",".join(reversed("ONE,ACER".split(","))))
```

This is my answer which I got
ACER,ONE